# DWT GetFieldMetadata Function

Tags: 2011, dwt

I just came across these built in functions for obtaining page metadata here:

https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/BuiltInFunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates
For example: !GetFieldMetadata("Image")=Name: Image

I've never use them so don't have an example to work with and the guesses i've made so far to use this function hasn't worked.

My page has a metadata schema with the field '**page_title**', so i'm trying to render this using:

```
@@GetFieldMetadata("page_title")@@
```

But this doesn't work.  I've tried the usual varieties "Page.Metadata.page_title", "Page.Metadata.Fields.page_title"

If anyone one has a quick solution, great, failing that i'm going back over to to a c# tbb :)

**Update:** Added a comment to Nick's comment below.

Comment: You can just do @@Metadata.page_title@@.  Not sure why you'd need a function for that.

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov - I had forgotten and have used  @@Page.Metadata.page_title@@ - i'd still like to know how to get the GetFieldMetadata function to work

Comment: Interesting! +1 for wanting to know if/what @@GetFieldMetadata("page_title")@@ adds over @@Page.Metadata.page_title@@.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This method doesn't get a metadata field... it gets a field's metadata.  For a Component with a multi-lined text field of "BodyText"...

```
@@GetFieldMetadata("BodyText")@@
```

Would return the following output:

```
Height: 10
DefaultValue: 
Name: BodyText
Description: BodyText
CustomUrl: 
MinOccurs: 0
MaxOccurs: 1
```

The function contains an optional 2nd argument which is a boolean that tells it whether or not the field is a metadata field or not, so for your example, you would want to do something along the lines of:

```
@@GetFieldMetadata("page_title", true)@@
```

The Default Dreamweaver Page Design and Default Dreamweaver Component Design templates also have a good example of putting this method to use  Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks alex - i couldn't see the wood for the trees.  that's interesting, i didn't know that was possible with dwt.  i certainly can't imagine a use-case for it but always good to know.

Comment: Use cases could be for testing and CMS designs! Walter van der Heiden had a post describing how he'd "inject" information (e.g. TCM urls) into just Staging markup for testing. I'm envisioning ways to create a page/content type breakdown auto-magically by adding schema and template name directly to markup. I believe the default templates use the `title` attribute to make a field's metadata look like a tooltip (based on your browser's functionality).

Comment: hi alvin, i get you - say a user doesn't enter a value it could display something in a certain scenario